# Getting text between brackets using regex and re

Tags: python, regex

I have an array of strings that I want to extract specific content from:

```
['link.description', 'button.text]] </li>']
```

I want to get the following output:

```
link.description
button.text
```

For each string in the array, I do the following:

```
str = re.findall('(.*?)\]+', str)
```

With the above regex, I can only get button.text. How would I get both link.description and button.text? I tried using:

```
str = re.findall('(.*?)\]*', str)
```

But the above just gives me a bunch of blanks in the return str.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need regex for a simple task like this. Besides, your code will probably make more sense without regex.

In this case, you can simply use `str.split()`:

```
>>> thingies = ['link.description', 'button.text]] </li>']
>>> different_thingies = [thingy.split(']')[0] for thingy in thingies]
>>> different_thingies
['link.description', 'button.text']
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm, try \]+. Is that what you want? (Asterisk says "match zero times or more" which -as you can see- matches really often.)