# Regex finding text between brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex question/issue. I want to find text between brackets. But if a bracket doesn't close before a new one opens, i want to ignore it. Take this for example:

> **Lorem ipsum [dolor [sit amet].**

I only want to get the "**[sit amet]**" part.

Here's what i've got so far:

```
\[([^\]]+)\]
```

[Test case](http://www.regexr.com/3a3is)

Comment: Include your current regex *in the question*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting text between brackets using regex and re](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509731/getting-text-between-brackets-using-regex-and-re)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple change to your regex is sufficient:

```
\[([^\[\]]+)\]
```

Simply don't allow an opening bracket `[` inside other brackets (ie disallow nesting).